# AutoComplete not showing data in list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

This is probably just an easy problem regarding something i'm overlooking, the code below retrieves data from the cache, so when I enter 'g' for example i get 3 results, or 'f' i get 1 results.

Problem is on the page with the AutoComplete, I get the dropdown below the textbox with 3 lines about 5px high when i enter 'g' or 1 when i enter 'f', but no text inside, or text that small i cannot see it to click.

But if i use the hardcoded values it work ok.

Can anyone spot what i'm missing.?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
{
    var wq = LocationList(term).Select(a => new
    {
        Value = a.strLocationName
    });
    return Json(wq, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private List<DisplayTopOneThousandAutoCompleteWeatherLocations> LocationList(string searchString)
{
    var wq = _IGTOTACWL.DisplayTopWeatherLocations()
        .Where(a => a.strLocationName.StartsWith(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

    return wq.ToList();
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SearchResults", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "frmWeather" })) 
{ 
<div id="dvWL"> 
    <ul id="ulWeatherSearch"> 
        <li> 
            <input id="wns" name="q" title="Change location" type="text"/></li> 
        <li> 
            <input id="wsb" name="b" type="submit" title="Click to search" value="Weather" /></li> 
    </ul> 
</div> 
<input id="hsho" name="o" type="hidden" value="5" /> 
} 
<p class="pIP">Location based on IP Address<br />@ViewBag.IPAddr</p> 
<script> 
    $("#wns").autocomplete({ 
    //source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ], 
    source: '@Url.Action("QuickSearch","Weather")' 
}); 
</script>
```

I have also tried the code below, but no luck

```
<script>
$("#wns").autocomplete({
//source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ],
    source: '@Url.Action("QuickSearch","Weather")',
    dataType: 'json',
    parse: function (data) {
        var rows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = { data: data[i].strLocationName};
        }
        return rows;
    },
    formatItem: function (row, i, n) {
        return row.strLocationName;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link below fixed my problem
[jquery-autocomplete](http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/jquery-autocomplete-with-aspnet-mvc.html)